# Filtering with NSPredicate - Data Type?

Tags: xcode, nspredicate

I wish to filter an array using a predicate but I'm being curved balled with the correct handling of data types.

First off, I have a list I want to filter with:

```
NSMutableArray *HospitalIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[HospitalIDs addObject: @"1"]; // Must be "id", int & NSInteger not accepted by XCode
[HospitalIDs addObject: @"2"]; // Must be "id", int & NSInteger not accepted by XCode
[HospitalIDs addObject: @"3"]; // Must be "id", int & NSInteger not accepted by XCode
```

Secondly, I have a list of objects that I want to filter using the array above:
(It's defined as NSMutableArray *HospitalObjects and is pre-populated with HospitalObjects)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.HospitalID IN %@", HospitalIDs];
[HospitalObjects filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%i",[HospitalObjects count]);

//The expected result is 3, but it prints 0.
```

WHY?

Because by first array contains NSString values, but my HospitalObject.HospitalID is of type int.

I don't really want to change the data type of HospitalID in my object definition to NSString, but I cannot filter on integer values, what do I do?

Can I convert the data type WITHIN the predicate syntax? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the best way to store numbers in `NSArray` is to use `NSNumber` objects. You can simply convert a `NSInteger` to `NSNumber` using [Objective-C literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

```
[HospitalIDs addObject: @(1)]; 
[HospitalIDs addObject: @(2)]; 
[HospitalIDs addObject: @(3)];
```

Then your predicate should work without any further changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Type [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html) that wraps ints, floats, bools, .. in a object.

```
NSMutableArray * hospitalIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[hospitalIDs addObject: @1]; // You can wrap an normal int into an NSNumber jusing @. In some siztuations you have to use @(yourOrdinaryValueTypeVariable)
[hospitalIDs addObject: @2];
[hospitalIDs addObject: @3];
```

By the way try to use proper naming using [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase):

- Classes start with a upper case: `SomeClassName`
- Objects, variables and method names with lower case: `SomeClassName* someObject;
- Constants are all upper case: `MY_CONSTANT`